# Laravel dynamic route parameter displays error 404

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to laravel and I am using version 5.7. I have problem with my dynamic route because whenever I use this get route:

```
Route::get('users/{$id}', function ($id) {
    return 'This is the user: ' . $id;
});
```

> localhost/users/John

It suppose to display the sentence with the user name specified in the url, but instead of that I am getting error saying 404 page could not be found.

---

## Solved

Apparently I was incorrectly providing route path. It should be `'users/{id}'` instead of `'users/{$id}'`. Removing $ sign fixed the issue.

Comment: It's `users/{id}`, not `users/{$id}`. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-parameters

Comment: Remove $ from users/{$id}

Route::get('users/{id}', function ($id) {
     return 'This is the user: ' . $id;
});

Comment: Please move your solution to an answer of its own, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is useful to read the documentation about [Laravel Route Parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-parameters).

Try this.

```
Route::get('users/{id}', function ($id) {
   return 'This is the user: ' . $id;
});
```

Comment: Yes that worked. I did not know that it should be done in this way and unfortunately I did not spot it correctly in the documentation. Thank you.

Comment: Please highlight the differences, such that the OP and others searching for help can learn from your answer

Comment: Gald to help you